# Initialization lists: using constructors in C++ vs Java

Tags: c++, header

ANSWERED

this is my first post on the website. I'm trying to construct a graph interface to run some graph algorithms in C++, but I'm having trouble getting my code to compile. I'm coming over from Java to C++ and basically, *what I'm trying to do is pass a Node (two times) to a constructor of an Edge class*. Perhaps the error is in the way I am including (re:title)? Node and Edge are two separate classes. This is my error:

```
Edge.cpp: In constructor ‘Edge::Edge(Node, Node, bool)’:
Edge.cpp:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘Node::Node()’
Node.h:10: note: candidates are: Node::Node(int)
Node.h:4: note:                 Node::Node(const Node&)
```

I realize that I don't have a Node() constructor defined, but I'm trying to pass an instance of Node to the Edge constructor, and I don't see where adding an (int) should come in. I hope my question is clear enough. I included the code I think is relevant (omitted Node.cpp and some of Edge.cpp). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

class Node {
protected:
    int label;
    int visited;

 public:
    Node(int label);
    int get_label();
    void visit();
    bool isVisited();
    void reset();
};
#endif
```

Edge.h

```
#ifndef EDGE_H
#define EDGE_H

class Node;

class Edge {
protected:
    Node n_one;
    Node n_two;
    bool directed;

public:
    Edge(Node n_one, Node n_two, bool directed);
    Node here();
    Node there();
    bool is_directed();

};
#endif
```

Edge.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "Edge.h"

Edge::Edge(Node n_one, Node n_two, bool directed) { //ERROR
    this->n_one = n_one;
    this->n_two = n_two;
    this->directed = directed;
}
```

....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, unless you specify otherwise, members of a class will be default constructed right before the constructor starts. So when your `Edge` constructor is invoked, it will try to default construct its two `Node` members, but they don't have default constructors. Then when you do `this->n_one = n_one`, for example, you are attempting to *copy assign* to the member `n_one`, rather than construct it using the copy constructor.

Instead, if you want to initialise members in a constructor, you should use a member initialization list:

```
Edge::Edge(Node n_one, Node n_two, bool directed)
  : n_one(n_one), n_two(n_two), directed(directed)
{ }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll change the title to reflect the error correctly

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of Edge is written incorrectly because the compiler tries to default initialize data members  Node n_one;  and Node n_two; but class Node has no the default constructor.

Rewrite the constructor of class Edge the following way

```
Edge::Edge(Node n_one, Node n_two, bool directed) : n_one( n_one ), n_two( n_two ), directed( directed ) 
{
}
```

Or it would be better to define it as

```
Edge::Edge( const Node &n_one, const Node &n_two, bool directed) : n_one( n_one ), n_two( n_two ), directed( directed ) 
{
}
```